# flutter: how to implement two routes in one icon

Tags: flutter

i'm using this code to implement sharing to social media icon in flutter, but i want this icon to show both when clicked instagram and facebook ( user choose between two routes) , is there a way to do it?

```html
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
       
          Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => shareOnFacebook(),
                ),
              );
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show a dialog box when social media icon is clicked. Dialog box will contain all the places where user can go(eg :- facebook, insta etc). Then you can implement click on individual item in the dialog box and navigate user to that item.